# Calculate the co-occurrence of a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I am trying to calculate the co-occurrence of some values in a vector in Matlab. I am using the following code to do so:

```
x = graph(:,1);
y = zeros(size(x));
for i = 1:length(x)
   y(i) = sum(x==x(i));
end
```

The above code calculates the co-occurrence of every index inside the vector. I want to have the co-occurrence of the unique indexes. How can I do so?

I found the following implementation:

```
a = unique(x);
out = [a,histc(x(:),a)];
```

However, I want the indexes to be as it is, without sorting.

Comment: `a = unique(x,'stable')`?

Comment: Using stable causing problems in out calculation, Error using histc
Edge vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see if this is what you need:

```
a=unique(x);
Coocurrence=zeros(length(a));

for ii=1:length(a)

    Coocurrence(ii)=sum(x==a(ii));

end
```

or the vectorized solution

```
a=unique(x);
Coocurrence=sum(bsxfun(@eq,x,a'),2);
```